# callback is not a function (but it is)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Probably this will be an easy question because I don't understand the concept of callback (I thought I did, but apparently no).

I'm trying to return a response from MySQL (easy thing to do in almost every language but with nodeJS):

I'm calling a function from my routes file:

route

```
const user = require('../models/Users');

router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
    let newUser = {
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    };
    if(user.checkIfUserExists) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

And here's the query inside another file:

```
const mysql = require('../handlers/mysql');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var User = {
    checkIfUserExists: function(newUser, callback) {
        mysql.query('SELECT * FROM users where Email like ?', [newUser.username], function(err, result) {
            if(err) return callback(err);
            callback(null, result > 0);
        });    
    },

    registerUser: function(newUser) {
        mysql.query("INSERT INTO users (Email, Password) VALUES (?, ?)", [newUser.username, User.hashPassword(newUser.password)], function(err, results) {
            if (err) throw err;
            return true;
        });
    },

    hashPassword: function(password) {
        let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
        return bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
    }    
}
module.exports = User;
```

Of course, same thing will happen with `registerUser`

Comment: You forget to call. user.checkIfUserExists(newUser, function(arg1, arg2) { //write code here handle the callback });

Comment: But that wouldn't check if the user exists, or I am missing something? @Nisfan

Comment: Please include the exact error message and the line of code producing the error. I don't see where in your code this error could be coming from.

Comment: @4castle the error is coming from the callback that would return `callback(null, result > 0);`

Comment: You are creating an hell of callbacks

Comment: How are you calling `checkIfUserExists`? `if (user.checkIfUserExists) {` isn't making a call to the function, so I don't see how it's possible for that code to be running.

Comment: @quirimmo I'm reading about callback hells, but I don't understand how to avoid them.
@4castle I'm calling `if (user.checkIfUserExists) {`

Comment: Promises - async/await -rxjs and so on

Comment: `user.checkIfUserExists` isn't a function call, it's just accessing the function at that property. A function call would look like `user.checkIfUserExists(...params...)`. Please show your actual code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forget to call and handle the callback.

```
user.checkIfUserExists(newUser, function(arg1, isUserExist) { 
    if (isUserExist) {
       //user exist
    }
});
```

Comment: Yup, this was the problem. Thanks! Solved using: `user.checkIfUserExists(newUser, (err, user) => { // do something });`

Answer (score 0):

You are not using callback. To do that follow the below code.

```
   `user.checkIfUserExists(newUser,(result)=>{
       If(result){
         //write your code  
         }
      }`
```

Answer (score -1):

Many guys have explained you problem. Let me explain you the concept of callback.

Callback is the function that is called, after a function has finished their job
For example, this function

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert('Alert will be ran after 3 seconds');
},3000);
```

You can open the developer mode (hit f12 on your browser and run it). You can see that the alert box will display after 3 seconds. I can explain the flow of code like this.

1. setTimeout function is run. This function will be finished after 3000 milliseconds, after that it will run the callback function
2. After 3000 milliseconds, the callback function is called. So the alert box is displayed.

In your code, you just create a plain new object, it does not have the checkIfUserExists function which is from the User object. You have to create user from the User class.

The callback function caused a lot of trouble to beginner, that's why in ES6+ (Javascript Version 6+). The class, async, await are introduced and make life easier.